# How does gcc know the register size to use in inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have the inline assembly code:

```
#define read_msr(index, buf)    asm volatile ("rdmsr" : "=d"(buf[1]), "=a"(buf[0]) : "c"(index))
```

The code using this macro:

```
u32 buf[2];

read_msr(0x173, buf);
```

I found the disassembly is (using gnu toolchain):

```
mov    eax,0x173
mov    ecx,eax
rdmsr  
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],edx
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],eax
```

The question is that 0x173 is less than 0xffff, why gcc does not use `mov cx, 0x173`? Will the gcc analysis the following instruction `rdmsr`? Will the gcc always know the correct register size?

Comment: I believe it's due to the type of `0x173` being `int`, so `gcc` uses the 32-bit `mov` instruction

Comment: `mov cx, 0x173` would not set `ecx` to 0x173. The upper 16 bits would contain whatever values were left over from earlier computation.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I know what you said. I want to know why gcc know that "ecx" must be used.

Comment: @RaymondChen I believe that the question was asking how GCC knows that the "c" constraint refers to `ecx` and not `cx` or `rcx`. If I'm correct, then your edit changes its meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the size of the value or variable passed.

If you pass a "short int" it will set "cx" and read the data from "ax" and "dx" (if buf is a short int, too).

For char it would access "cl" and so on.

So "c" refers to the "ecx" register, but this is accessed with "ecx", "cx", or "cl" depending on the size of the access, which I think makes sense.

To test you can try passing (unsigned short)0x173, it should change the code.

There is no analysis of the inline assembly (in fact it is after text substitution direclty copied to the output assembly, including syntax errors). Also there is no default register size, depending on whether you have a 32 or 64 bit target. This would be way to limiting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is because the current default data size is 32-bit. In 64-bit long mode, the default data size is also 32-bit, unless you use "rex.w" prefix.

Comment: No, `0x173` in C has type `int`, which is a 32-bit type in the x86-64 System V ABI.  *That's* why it picked a 32-bit register for `"c"(0x173)`.  It's not a coincidence that `int` is the same size as the default operand-size, but those are separate things.  (e.g. `gcc -m16` targeting 16-bit mode still uses 32-bit int and pointers, even though that requires the assembler to use operand-size and address-size prefixes on most instructions.  And on non-x86, e.g. AVR, `int` needs 2 registers.)

Answer (score -2):

Intel specifies the RDMSR instruction as using (all of) ECX to determine the model specific register.   That being the case, and apparently as specified by your macro, GCC has every reason to load your constant into the full ECX.

So the question about why it doesn't load CX seems completely inappropriate.  It looks like GCC is generating the right code.

(You didn't ask why it stages the load of ECX inefficiently by using EAX; I don't know the answer to that).

Comment: GCC doesn't work this way. The only thing that determines which register is assigned is the constraint and the size of the type. GCC doesn't analyze the instructions themselves. It couldn't even if it wanted to, because there could be more than one instruction.

Comment: As noted, his macro established the constraint on ECX.  To the extent that GCC *does* know the register requirements for RDMSR (it may not know, I'm not a GCC expert), so if OP has specified CX somehow, the RDMSR code generator would have objected that it did not get a full value.

Comment: If you acknowledge that you don't know if GCC behaves this way, why write in your answer that it does? As I said, GCC cannot possibly behave this way, because there could be other instructions preceding `rdmsr` in the inline assembly, including possibly branch instructions, and knowing which instruction is the one that uses `ecx` is as difficult as solving the halting problem.

Comment: And if only `cx` was assigned, the code generator wouldn't give an error as you claim: it would simply use the previous contents of the high-order bits.

Comment: Its clear OP is confused about setting CX for the purposes of RDMSR. It is clear he specified the "C" register to get set with the value.  I don't know specifically what the GCC code generator does with instructions, but it is pretty sophisticated and I can imagine (perhaps wrongly) that it understands what the input and output requirements are for each instruction.  While it might not be able to determine if a bit of custom assembly code set the registers *correctly*, it has the reseasonable potential to determine if the register ECX is NOT SET and thus could complain if only CX were set.

Comment: ... So it was clear to me, at least, that OP was getting the right code for two different reasons, even if one of them is only potential and not actually implemented.   Lastly, to confuse the issue, OP changed the question.